# Python Pandas unable to overwrite a csv file "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have found many answers relating to Errno 22 but nothing pandas specific and nothing where it is only on overwrite not on write (initial write succeeds).

So ive managed to recreate the bug with the following python script:

```
import pandas as pd

print('path:')
path = input()

data = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3], columns=['index'])
data.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)

data = data.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[4,5,6], columns=['index']))
data.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

so the first call to to_csv writes the following file

```
index
1
2
3
```

but the second call to to_csv causes the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '[path omitted]/python/bug'
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i have found is to use os.remove(path):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

print('path:')
path = input()

data = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3], columns=['index'])
data.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)

if(os.path.exists(path)):
    os.remove(path)

data = data.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[4,5,6], columns=['index']))
data.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

its a shame to_csv doesnt have an overwrite mode

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataFrame.update` function documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html). It allows for overwriting data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3], columns=['index'])
data.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)

newData = pd.DataFrame(data=[4,5,6], columns=['index'])
data.update(newData, join='left', overwrite=True, filter_func=None, raise_conflict=False)
data.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: i have edited my post to reflect this, however the error still occurs