# Cannot save pandas dataframe to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, error-handling, data-science

Solved: Pandas version is outdated. 
I try many times but cannot save my pandas dataframe to csv file. Every time, it has error. Please see the pictures. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGOxa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQc0C.png)

Comment: show us the full code please. :)

Comment: post your code that you tried along with error

Comment: Please see the screenshots. Thank you!

Comment: please have a look at other questions on StackOverflow and then post your code. Don't add images of your code.

Comment: Please include the error message as text and not as an image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464269/python-pandas-unable-to-overwrite-a-csv-file-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argume
Check this. The `to_csv` method can't overwrite files.

Comment: Your pandas version might be old. what is the output of `pd.show_versions()`? Check this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21346

Comment: I will try all suggestions. Thank you! It takes time to overwrite all data.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case Pandas can't overwrite the existing file. But without the data and the full code we can't really help you.

Have a look to this solutions:

[Python Pandas unable to overwrite a csv file "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464269/python-pandas-unable-to-overwrite-a-csv-file-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argume)

Answer (score 0):

My Pandas was outdated(0.23.1). I updated it to new one (0.23.4) and there is not issue anymore.